# Git insists on merging, after a mistaken push - how to avoid that?

Tags: git, version-control

I had a local repository, which I wanted to push online - which I did.

Then I did a test checkout to a second local repo - all fine.

Then I made a new commit locally in the first local, and pushed it - turns out it was under a wrong username. Since I couldn't just amend it, now that it was pushed. I decided to delete the remote repo and start all over. When doing that, I pushed from the second local repo, as it was untouched.

Back to the first local repo, I tried doing a git pull - now for some reason, `git` automatically wants to do a merge?! This is the state `gitk` reports after that:

[image: gitk.png]

As you can see, the "remotes/origin/master" points to commit "more ...", the last local one also points to the very same commit - and then `git` still insists on doing a merge?! (note: this is the last original commit that I pushed, before I made the mistaken commit, which is now no longer visible in the first repo)

How can I somehow reset the first local repo, so when I do the pull in it,, `git` recognizes that the remote "more..." and local "more..." are the same commit, and it does NOT perform an automatic merge anymore?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** because you amended the commit in one repo and left it unchanged in the other, git sees them as two different commits and wants to merge them if you do `git pull` with merging strategy.

When you pushed from your second repo, you pushed exactly the same repository as the one you deleted before: your second repository is a copy of the remote one. So your second repository, as well as the remote repository holds the first version of the commit with, I guess (since you hid it) the *wrong* username.

So you're back in the same situation: Your first repository is out of sync because it contains a different commit. The content of the commit might be the same but no the metadata (you amended your commit to change the username). That's why git wants to merge it.

What you wanted to do was to delete the remote, push the first repo, delete the second repo and clone the second repo again. (If you pull from the un-deleted second repo you will have the same problem there).
Simpler: After you pushed the first repo you could do `git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master`

**Note:** You could have done a `git push -f origin master` from the first repo instead of deleting the repo. (force push)

The normal way to fix your issue would have been:

```
host:repo1$ git commit --amend --reset-author
host:repo1$ git push -f origin master 
host:repo1$ cd ../repo2
host:repo2$ git fetch
host:repo2$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
host:repo2$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment if you have any question regarding the steps i described.